# styling a php form submit button

Tags: html, css, forms

I am echoing a form from database based on some user input conditions. Form will contain 2 buttons. i have successfully completed it. I just wanna style the buttons inside the form (buttons for further steps). I have no idea how to style the button inside the php form.

```
$result = $conn->query ($sql);

if($result ->num_rows>0){
    echo '<table >';

    while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<tr><th>Romm Number</th>';
        echo '<td >' . $row['Number']. '</td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><th>Room Temperature</th>';
        echo '<td >' . $row['TEMP']. '</td></tr>';

        //wanna style following form buttons

        echo "<form action = 'script.php' method =post>";
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td > "." <input type=submit    name=alarm value=Alarm> "."  </td>";
        echo "<td >"." <input type=hidden  name=view  value ='A'> "."  </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</form>";

        echo "<form action = 'script2.php' method =post>";
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td >"." <input type=submit  name=control value='Log'> "." </td>";
        echo "<td >"." <input type=hidden  name=graph  value ='B'> "."  </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</form>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}else {
    echo "no result";
}

//mysqli_free_result($result);
$conn->close();
}
```

Any suggestions to style form buttons inside php table?

Comment: With `css` just like everything else.

Comment: where's the problem? you can add a class to the button and then write the relative rules. P.s. you have some error in your code (type='submit'),

Comment: <input type=submit  name=control value='Log' class = "buttonClass">       something like this?

Comment: Add class="submit_button" to them and add css style for that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use style within the html tag like

```
echo "<td >"." <input type='submit' name=control value='Log' style='color:yellow;font-size:20px;border:none' class="submit"> "." </td>";
```

(or)

Add specific class to the button and write css for it, for example:

```
.submit {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: @dayDreamer If it works you can mark it as such by pressing the tick icon underneath the answer score `<----`. Cheers `:-)`